# getting garbage values while converting Yii model object to JSON

Tags: php, yii

i have a model class which extends CComponent

```
    class CompanyModel extends CComponent{ 
    private $company_pk;
    public function getCompany_pk()
   {
        return $this->company_pk;
   }
   public function setCompany_pk($value)    {
        $this->company_pk = $value;
    }
}
```

I have a function which fills this modal

```
    public function getCompanyList() {
    $companyList=array();
    $company_obj = new CompanyModel();
    $sql = "SELECT company_pk,name FROM tbl_company WHERE status = ".Constants::ACTIVE_COMPANY;
    $command=$this->connection->createCommand($sql);
    $command->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rows=$command->queryAll();

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $company_obj->company_pk = $row['company_pk'];
        array_push($companyList,$company_obj);

    }

    return $companyList;
}
```

and my controller

```
    Class UserController extends CController {
public  function actionGetCompanyList() {
    $model = new UserAction();
    $ret_val = $model->getCompanyList();
    echo CJSON::encode((array)$ret_val[0]);
         }
     }
```

and the JSON i get is

```
{"\u0000CompanyModel\u0000company_pk":"2"}
```

How can i remove those garbage values

Comment: Those are unicode characters code point, not garbage values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if i extend CModel instead of CComponent in the model class, i could achieve what exactly i wanted. While extending this class you will have to override one abstract method. Otherwise it will throw error. My new Model class look like this

```
   class CompanyModel extends CModel{ 
private $company_pk;
public function attributeNames()
{
    return array( 'company_pk' );
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array( 'company_pk' => 'company_pk Label' );
}
public function getCompany_pk()
   {
    return $this->company_pk;
   }
public function setCompany_pk($value)    {
    $this->company_pk = $value;
}
}
```

Comment: Because CModel implements IteratorAggregate ;) So basically my answer still valid. Funny what you are doing with `public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array( 'company_pk' => 'company_pk Label' );
}` is the exactly the same i suggested, they just internaly map all your properties provided in  your array ;) Anyway good that you found Yii approach of doing it.

Comment: Yup, i had checked the code in CModel and i know your answer is still valid. I tried to accept both answers, but doesn't work that way here ;). I am pretty new to Yii and PHP. Hence the troubles :). And i think attribute label is not important, it is attributeNames important

Answer (score 1):

I asume you can't decode them later, if you would change `$company_pk` to public it should encode correctly. Problem is with your object cast to array which adds NULL byte to your private member `$company_pk`. In `echo CJSON::encode((array)$ret_val[0]);` as it's array of OBJECTS.

You can do nasty.

```
$json = '{"\u0000CompanyModel\u0000company_pk":"2"}';

$json = str_replace('\u0000', '', $json);

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Or you pass object to `CJSON::encode` i dont know much of YII but it should handle object, as per manual http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON.

Here is example to reproduce issue:

```
class test {
 private $private = 1;
 public $publiv = 2;
}

$obj = new test();
$array = (array) $obj;

$json = json_encode($array);

var_dump($json);

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

**EDIT**:

From the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php:

> > If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

I did quick look to `CJSON::encode` from YII and you can use object directly, but your object must be traversable, so you must implement Iterator interface. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php.

EDIT:2

Implementing interface could be tricky, there is another option to call `get_object_vars` from within object and in this case you will get array which will work.

```
class CompanyModel extends CComponent
{
    private $company_pk;

    public function getCompany_pk()
    {
        return $this->company_pk;
    }
    public function setCompany_pk($value)
    {
        $this->company_pk = $value;
    }

    public function export()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
```

}

And then:

```
$ret_val = $model->getCompanyList();
echo CJSON::encode($ret_val->export());
```

Problem why it does not work for you with normal object because YII uses `get_object_vars` internally and it can't access private properties when it's in different scope.

Comment: if i don't type cast it into array, i will not get anything inside the JSON output. like `CJSON::encode($ret_val[0])`

Comment: Then you can remove private and make in public, or clean with `str_replace`. When you cast  object containing private members to array you will get null byte added.

Comment: do you mean change in the model? can you tell me how it should look like?

Comment: by changing `private $company_pk;` to `public $company_pk;`.

Comment: But that is not the way to create properties, right? Do you know any way to create a Model class with properties in Yii?

Comment: Yes you will break encapsulation. I have updated my answer with more details. Now you have 3 ways to solve it, strip NULL BYTES, change properties visibility or make object traversable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but i still am getting some kind of error on implementing this interface. It would be great if you can give me a small example of model class on Yii

Comment: Ok i have fourth way to do it :)

Comment: let me try it and let you know

Comment: that went well, thank you very much. Question for you though. If i have an array of company objects, will this work?

Comment: No. It's only for one object.

Comment: Do you see any solution for that? Because that situation comes a lot usually.

Comment: It's out of scope of your question. I have provided you solutions you can also make it work with array of objects, dont me lazy and think a little bit ;)

Comment: if you are saying about looping, i think that would be not a good idea from performance perspective. I wanted the best practice, that's why i asked here

Comment: You asked, 'How can i remove those garbage values' i have explained it in detail and even with examples. There is no good practice for such case because you want to export private which is by idea should be hidden, that's why i am suggesting these hacks, want your data be visible outside make it public.